# how to get range class of objectProperty by its domain class in owlapi?

Tags: owl-api

In my project, I'd like to get all the range class related to the given class by an restricted(somevaluefrom or allvalues from) objectproperties. I can get the restricted subclassofAxioms expressions including the given class, but how can I get the range class in these expressions? In other word, how can I get all the related classes to the given class excluding inherited subclass.

For example:

```
public static void printSubClassOfAxioms(OWLOntology ontology,OWLReasoner reasoner,OWLClass owlClass){  

  for(OWLSubClassOfAxiom ax:ontology.getSubClassAxiomsForSubClass(owlClass)){
        OWLClassExpression expression=ax.getSuperClass();
        System.out.println(ax);
         System.out.println(expression);
    }
 }
```

The results are:

```
SubClassOf(<#FourCheesesTopping> <#CheeseTopping>)  
SubClassOf(<#FourCheesesTopping> ObjectSomeValuesFrom(<#hasSpiciness> <#Mild>))  
SubClassOf(<#FourCheesesTopping> ObjectAllValuesFrom(<#hasCountryOfOrigin> #Country>))
```

How can I just get the range classes #Country and #Mild

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an OWLObjectVisitor and override the visit(OWL... Type) for the restrictions you're interested in. At that point,

```
type.getFiller()
```

will yield the class you're after.

Examples are in the documentation: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation

```
public class RestrictionVisitor extends OWLClassExpressionVisitor {
    @Override
    public void visit(@Nonnull OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom ce) {
        // This method gets called when a class expression is an existential
        // (someValuesFrom) restriction and it asks us to visit it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you mean to create an OWLObjectVisitor class, and override the visit method in it, then instantiate the class, and invoke the method in the above function to get the range class? May I bother you to give me an example?

Comment: The OWLAPI documentation has such examples: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation